# Implementation of hashCode in PrimaryKeyClass of spring-data-cassandra

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am using `spring-data-cassandra` and have a table such that
its primary key is `((int_col1,int_col2),bigint_col1,bigint_col2)`.
 `int_col1`&`int_col2` are the partition keys
`bigint_col1` & `bigint_col2` are the cluster keys.

How important is it to implement `hashcode` & `equals` method for my class.
What should be the `hashcode` implementation of my above `@PrimaryKeyClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your class's constructor should have exactly four arguments
// and ensure that each of these four fields are non-null

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return 37
    ^ int_col1.hashCode()
    ^ int_col2.hashCode()
    ^ bigint_col1.hashCode()
    ^ bigint_col2.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
  if (this == that) {
    return true;
  }
  if (that == null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!(that instanceof YourPrimaryKeyClass)) {
    return false;
  }
  YourPrimaryKeyClass other = (YourPrimaryKeyClass) that;
  return this.int_col1.equals(other.int_col1)
    && this.int_col2.equals(other.int_col2)
    && bigint_col1.equals(other.bigint_col1)
    && bigint_col2.equals(other.bigint_col2);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathew, could you plz explain your hashcode implementation.